# SQL to LINQ - multiple tables left outer join with where clause referring right table

Tags: c#, linq

I have this following query and want to convert to LINQ.

I have tried LINQPad and Linqer but getting an error in Visual Studio.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                g.TXT_Property,
                up.TXT_Page
            FROM MD g

            LEFT JOIN MD ux ON ux.TXT_Page = @sPage 
                AND ux.TXT_Property = g.TXT_Property 
                AND ux.TXT_Product = @sProdAll 
                AND ux.GID_Section IS NULL

            LEFT JOIN MD up ON up.TXT_Page = @sPage 
                AND up.TXT_Property = g.TXT_Property 
                AND (ISNULL(up.TXT_Product, '') = @sProd or up.TXT_Product = @sProdAlt) 
                AND up.GID_Section IS NULL
            WHERE 

                (g.GID_Section IS NULL) 
                AND g.TXT_Page = @sPage 
                and (ISNULL(g.TXT_Product, '') = @sProd or g.TXT_Product = @sProdAlt or g.TXT_Product = @sProdAll)
            ORDER BY TXT_Property, TXT_Product, TXT_Language
```

This what I have tried:

```
                var query2 = from g in list
                             join ux in list
                                  on g.Property equals ux.Property into g_ux
                             where ux.Page == sPage
                             && ux.Product == sProdAll
                             && ux.Section == null
```

And this is another try.

I have referred to 
[SQL to LINQ - multiple tables left outer join with where clause referring right table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158441/sql-to-linq-multiple-tables-left-outer-join-with-where-clause-referring-right)

// Another query

```
var query = (from g in
                                 ((from d in list
                                   where ((d.Section == null || d.Section == uSection) && (d.Product == sProd || (sProd == "" && d.Product == null) || (d.Product == sProdAlt) || (d.Product == sProdAll)))
                                   select (new { d.Property })).ToList())

                             join gx in
                                 ((from d in list
                                   where (d.Section == null) && (d.Product == sProdAll)
                                   select (new { d.Property, d.Page, d.Product, d.Language, d.Value, d.Section })).ToList())
                                     on g.Property equals gx.Property into res1
                             from a1 in res1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             join gp in
                                 ((from d in list
                                   where (d.Section == null) && (d.Product == sProd || (sProd == "" && d.Product == null) || (d.Product == sProdAlt))
                                   select (new { d.Property, d.Page, d.Product, d.Language, d.Value, d.Section })).ToList())
                                   on g.Property equals gp.Property into res2
                             from a2 in res2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             join ux in
                                 ((from d in list
                                   where (d.Section == uSection) && (d.Product == sProdAll)
                                   select (new { d.Property, d.Page, d.Product, d.Language, d.Value, d.Section })).ToList())
                                   on g.Property equals ux.Property into res3
                             from a3 in res3.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             join up in
                                 ((from d in list
                                   where (d.Section == uSection) && (d.Product == sProd || (sProd == "" && d.Product == null) || (d.Product == sProdAlt))
                                   select (new { d.Property, d.Page, d.Product, d.Language, d.Value, d.Section })).ToList())
                                     on g.Property equals up.Property into res4
                             from a4 in res4.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             orderby (new
                             {
                                 TXT_Property = g.Property,
                                 TXT_Product = Coalesce((Coalesce(a4.Page, "") == "" ? Coalesce(a4.Product, a3.Product) : Coalesce(a4.Product, "SA")), a3.Product, (Coalesce(a2.Page, "") == "" ? Coalesce(a2.Product, a1.Product) : Coalesce(a2.Product, "SA")), a1.Product),
                                 TXT_Language = Coalesce(a4.Language, a3.Language, a2.Language, a1.Language),
                             })
                             select (new
                             {
                                 TXT_Property = g.Property,
                                 TXT_Product = Coalesce((Coalesce(a4.Page, "") == "" ? Coalesce(a4.Product, a3.Product) : Coalesce(a4.Product, "SA")), a3.Product, (Coalesce(a2.Page, "") == "" ? Coalesce(a2.Product, a1.Product) : Coalesce(a2.Product, "SA")), a1.Product),
                                 TXT_Language = Coalesce(a4.Language, a3.Language, a2.Language, a1.Language),
                                 TXT_Value = Coalesce(a4.Value, a3.Value, a2.Value, a1.Value)
                             }));
```

Comment: You may want to post some of the code you have attempted or else you are likely to get down votes and may not get much in the way of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query seems very questionable to me (since ux is a `LEFT JOIN` and (presumably) not referenced in the rest of the query, it adds nothing), and I had to assume the `ORDER BY` was on the `g` columns since it wasn't specified (and I am surprised that isn't rejected by SQL as ambiguous), but here is my try at the translation:

```
var ans = from g in MD
          join ux in MD on new { TXT_Page = sPage, g.TXT_Property, TXT_Product = sProdAll, GID_Section = (string)null } equals new { ux.TXT_Page, ux.TXT_Property, ux.TXT_Product, ux.GID_Section } into uxj
          from ux in uxj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join up in MD on new { TXT_Page = sPage, g.TXT_Property, GID_Section = (string)null } equals new { up.TXT_Page, up.TXT_Property, up.GID_Section } into upj
          from up in upj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where up == null || (up.TXT_Product ?? "") == sProd || up.TXT_Product == sProdAlt
          where g.GID_Section == null && g.TXT_Page == sPage &&
                ((g.TXT_Product ?? "") == sProd || g.TXT_Product == sProdAlt || g.TXT_Product == sProdAll)
          orderby g.TXT_Property, g.TXT_Product, g.TXT_Language
          select new { g.TXT_Property, up.TXT_Page };
```

Note: I put in the `up == null` because because otherwise the `where` might reject where the `LEFT JOIN` in SQL wouldn't.

I assumed the type of `GID_Section` was `string`, but you can cast the `null`s to the right type.

Here is my SQL conversion recipe, though your SQL was a bit trickier since it combined `LEFT JOIN` and non-equijoin.

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate `FROM` subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, translating monadic and aggregate operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc) into functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new {` ... `}`) for multiple columns.
5. `JOIN` conditions that aren't all equality tests with `AND` must be handled using `where` clauses outside the join, or with cross product (`from` ... `from` ...) and then `where`
6. `JOIN` conditions that are multiple `AND`ed equality tests between the two tables should be translated into anonymous objects
7. `LEFT JOIN` is simulated by using `into` *joinvariable* and doing another from `from` the *joinvariable* followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
8. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator (`?:`)and a `null` test.
9. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`, using literal arrays or array variables for constant lists.
10. Translate *x* `BETWEEN` *low* `AND` *high* to *low* `<=` *x* `&&` *x* `<=` *high*.
11. Translate `CASE` to the ternary conditional operator `?:`.
12. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
13. `SELECT` fields must be replaced with `select new {` ... `}` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
14. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.